# Change cell color base on another cells data but keep it that way if data changes again

Tags: excel, macros, conditional-formatting, vba

I have been looking for days to solve this and have only come up with half the solution.

**What I can do:**

I would simply like to have one cell turn green inside with an x inserted when another cells data has the word "Complete" inside it.

**What I cannot do:**

I would like that same cell that turned green with an x inserted into it when the word "Complete" is changed to "Rework" to stay green with an x.

So Cell A1 is blank then in cell B1 the word "Complete" is added. Then cell A1 changes to green and has an x inside it. If later B1 changes to "Rework" I would like A1 to stay green with the x inside. So I can know that at one time the status of B1 was at one time "Complete"

I have been trying Conditional Formatting with rules but cannot get it to stay. I think the "Stop If True" check box within would be part of the solution but not sure what the code would be.

I already have a different macro running on this sheet so if the answer is a macro I will need it to be added to it. Below is the macro in the sheet already. Thank you.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N:N,Y:Y"), Range("10:" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count < Columns.Count Then
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Dim r As Range
            For Each r In Intersect(Target, Range("N:N,Y:Y"), Range("10:" & Rows.Count))
                With r.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = Now   'use Now to retain the time as well as the date
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"  'change to what you prefer
                End With
            Next r
        End If
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need a column to capture the past status, and probably VBA to calculate the value.

Comment: @OldUgly - Not necessarily, he may not need a helper column, I think. He could use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, to get the cell's value *before* the change is made.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yep. And the cells color is "memory" of the past value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd split this up into separate subs to handle each of the change types, but this should give you an idea:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r as Range

    'skip full-row changes (row insert/delete?)
    If Target.Columns.Count = Columns.Count Then Exit Sub

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("N:N,Y:Y"), Range("10:" & Rows.Count))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rng.Cells
            With r.Offset(0, 1)
                .Value = Now   'use Now to retain the time as well as the date
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"  'change to what you prefer
            End With
        Next r

    End If

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"), Range("10:" & Rows.Count))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rng.Cells
            If r.Value = "Complete" Then
                With r.Offset(0, -1)
                    .Value = "x"
                    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End With '<<EDIT thanks @BruceWayne
            End If
        Next r
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to be the right direction but I have tried it and keep getting the Complie error: End If without block If . The End If right after the .Interior.Color = vbGreen is highlighted. I have tried to resolve this but have a limited understanding of VBC coding. I can only piece code together from other codes or slightly alter code. I'm not really sure how to "split this up into separate subs to handle each of the change types"

Comment: @belau - That's a typo, that `End If` should be `End With`.  See if that fix helps it.

Comment: OK so the error is fixed but nothing happens. So I start with cell in column Y blank then change to status of "Need to Work" and the date is added in same row of column Z so far good (same for cells in columns N and O) then I change cell of column Y to "Complete" but nothing happens. Is Green with an x supposed to be added to cell in column B? If so this does not happen. Also the goal is that if cell in column Y changes from "Complete" to "Rework" need the x and green to stay in cell of column B.

Comment: Of course nothing happens because *in your question you talk about columns A and B*, so that's how I wrote it.  It should be pretty obvious what you need to change.

Comment: Oh I think I get it! I'll try.

Comment: If you only want to monitor columns N and Y then you only need the single block of code  - you can move the check for "Complete" into the first loop.

Comment: Wow sorry. I misread it with my limited ability to read it but thought the ("B:B") was refereeing to the column that would change not noticing the same logic of the With r.Offset(0, -1) I get so intimidated when it comes to coding because having just one misplaced . can ruin it. Seems to work pro!!! Thank you for your help!

Comment: actually for this x and green add it works good because I only need to monitor Y and it does so.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two worksheet events, and some `If` statements.  The following should help you get started, unless I'm overlooking something.

```
Dim oldVal as String  ' Public variable

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Debug.Print Target.Address
If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
oldVal = Target.Value
End Sub
```

The above will make note of the oldValue.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim newVal As String
newVal = Target.Value

If newVal = oldVal Then
    Debug.Print "Same Values"
ElseIf oldVal = "Complete" And newVal = "Rework" Then
    Debug.Print "Stay green with X"
ElseIf oldVal = "" And (newVal = "Complete" Or newVal = "complete") Then
    Debug.Print "Change cell to Green, add an 'X'"
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    Target.Value = Target.Value & " x"
End If

End Sub
```

Then, add/tweak those If statements as necessary, and add the color changing/reverting code to the appropriate block.

(There may of course be a better mousetrap, but I think this should get you going).

Comment: Your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` will throw a "type mismatch" error if the more than a single cell is selected (because the `Value` type will be variant array and not String)

Comment: @TimWilliams - Ah, good catch! I've updated that part. I just exit the sub if the range is more than one cell.

Comment: Thanks! This does have a few issue. The one you stated already is a big issue because we will often select multiple cells. Another is that "Rework" is just one example of what the text could change to from being Complete. But the biggest is that this does work but it puts the green in the same cell and puts the x at the end of the word Complete in the same cell. The x does disappear after the status changes from Complete to another but the green does stay so we could just get rid of the x as long as the green works in a different cell on that same row.